# Include a PDF (contain a table) and get an entry of it into the list of tables

Tags: tables, graphics, table-of-contents

How to include a PDF in a document and getting an entry of it into the list of tables?
I have three doc (pdf) contain tables I would like to put them on latex (include them as an only table and put caption "summary table" just one caption at the end, how to do this please and how to add the title of my table (page as well) on my list of tables

```
\includegraphics{tableofcontentmanually/file1.pdf}
\includegraphics{tableofcontentmanually/file2.pdf}
\includegraphics{tableofcontentmanually/file3.pdf}
```

here is my tables on pdfs :) thank you for your time and consideration[image: tables]

Comment: In the future: please consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the tables in the pdf are already cropped to the correct size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\caption{test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your time and consideration :)  it works well just how to minimize the space between the title and the the pdf I have imported ( the table !) and thank you again dear samcarter

Comment: @mirette As a quick hack you could try `\vspace*{-0.5cm}`, but this is just a guess. If you want an helpful answer, we would need a MWE and see how your table looks like, for example is the pdf cropped exactly to the table or is there whitespace around ...

Answer (score 3):

With `pdfpages` and its `addtolist` option, say `addtolist={1,table,My wonderful table,table::wonderfultable}` in order to add the first page of a `.pdf` file to the `list of tables`, give it the caption `My wonderful table` and the `label` `table::wonderfultable` which works with `\ref` as well then.

This works for any float like `figure` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\listoftables


See \ref{table::wonderfultable}



\includepdf[scale=0.5,addtolist={1,table,My wonderful table,table::wonderfultable}]{7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `7.pdf` file is generated from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Beginning \jobname}
\blindtext[50]
\end{document}
```

Comment: dear Christian excuse me  what could be the reason I have not get the title of the table ( caption in the bottom, is it with no caption !! ) and thank you for your essay am really very gratefull :)

Comment: @mirette: Sorry, I don't understand. The included table pdf. does not have a caption by using `\includepdf`. The caption is the title in the List of Tables.

Comment: yeah but It does not appear under my imported pdf ! it is okey it appears on my list of tables but there is no title under my  the imported pdf